# How to crop image in HTML 5?

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I am working on a responsive site in which background is a large image as seen in the first image.

If I reduce the width of the browser automatically left and right edges should get trimmed like as shown in the second image. Center is focused.

How to do this?

[image: screen1]

[image: screen2]

Comment: Use `background-position: center center`

Comment: @BenM I thought that at first be he is saying to scale I guess

Comment: @Mr.Alien : not scaling

Comment: @AngelGuy so go with what ben commented

Comment: So, do you want to actually crop the image with `HTML5` or just resize and position it with `CSS` ?

Comment: @Cristy when browser width is scaled the image is focused to the center. that is when reduced.

Comment: @AngelGuy In that case you only have to scale the image and position it with `CSS`. You do not need any `HTML5` features for this :)

Answer (score 1):

@AngelGuy ,

use the following css :

```
background-image:url('bigImg.jpg');
background-size:cover; 
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

For a particular screen size with fixed height, resizing the width of the browser will not resize the image, the edges of the image will be trimmer.

Comment: yes, this will work if the height and width of the div does not change with resizing the browser. Try :
<div style="background-image:url('bigImg.jpg');background-size:cover; background-repeat:no-repeat; height:700px; width:1000px;"></div>